# How to use Python and matplotlib to customize a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar chart from a dictionary for Eg:

```
Dic = OrderedDict([('PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES', 621), ('WEB_SEARCH', 381), ('REMOTE_ACCESS', 160), ('Microsoft Category', 141), ('INTERNET_SERVICES', 62)])
```

I want to get a bar chart like the one in the following screenshot:

[image: bar chart sample]

Here is the code that I am using so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  Processesing import dataProcess

def chartmak (dic) :
    D={}
    D=dic
    plt.barh(range(len(D)), D.values(),align='center',color="#add8e6")
    plt.xticks(D.values, D.keys())
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()
```

NB: I am calling this function from another `.py` file

Any idea if it is possible to get a bar chart like the one in the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import OrderedDict

def chartmak (dic) :
    plt.barh(range(len(dic)), dic.values(), 0.95, align='center', color="lightskyblue")
    plt.yticks(range(len(dic)), ["{} GB".format(v) for v in dic.values()])
    for index, label in enumerate(dic.keys()):
        plt.text(10, index, label, ha='left',va='center')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()

Dic = OrderedDict([('PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES', 621), ('WEB_SEARCH', 381), ('REMOTE_ACCESS', 160), ('Microsoft Category', 141), ('INTERNET_SERVICES', 62)])
chartmak(Dic)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will get you started. You can use `annotate` to add text labels at a specified point (in data coordinates) and explicitly set the y-tick labels. You can also turn off the border "spines" and remove the tick marks to get a closer look to the image you provide.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Dic = OrderedDict([('PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES', 621), ('WEB_SEARCH', 381), ('REMOTE_ACCESS', 160), ('Microsoft Category', 141), ('INTERNET_SERVICES', 62)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
n = len(Dic)
ax.barh(range(n), Dic.values(), align='center', fc='#80d0f1', ec='w')
ax.set_yticks(range(n))
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:3d} GB'.format(e) for e in Dic.values()], color='gray')
ax.tick_params(pad=10)
for i, (label, val) in enumerate(Dic.items()):
    ax.annotate(label.title(), xy=(10, i), fontsize=12, va='center')
for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer it look exactly like the screenshot. do you have any idea where i can find some tutorial about matplotlib ? thanks

Comment: A lot of people recommend the [Matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) -- pick one that looks a bit like what you want and modify its code. There's also a short series of Matplotlib examples on [this website](http://scipython.com/book/chapter-7-matplotlib/examples/).